# Debugging connectivity issue to a website

Tags: firewall, connection

How can we debug the connectivity issues to a website https://test.mysite.office.net? From public networks, this URL is accessible.

From our network we are not able to access it. But Ping works fine, tracert works fine, telnet fails. There are multiple firewalls between our network and the internet. Is there some tool, or command that can tell that, it's at this place where the request is blocked?

Comment: It isn't accessible from here. The hostname appears to not exist.

Comment: Ping works and it shows the actual IP address of destination. So it should be the firewall issue right?

Comment: wireshark should be of help to you if the paket is rejected at firewall X, for showing which firewall drops: change your FW settings from drop to reject, then check the hop count (sry forgot the exact name)